# What does "rm -rf" do with "/*" in it?

Tags: command-line, rm

> **Warning:
>
>   To avoid catastrophic data loss, readers should NOT run this, *nor any variations on it!***

I would like to understand what does this command do: `sudo rm -rf/*`

Comment: rm (remove files) -r (recursive) -f (force) /*  (starting in / or root directory) ; the `sudo` elevates privileges.  you can `man rm` to read the manual page for rm

Comment: It deletes everything on your disk(s). **Do not run this unless you want to destroy your installation and lose all files on your computer!**

Comment: It will give an error because of a typo.

Comment: @xiota Where is the typo?

Comment: @Helen the typo is that there should be a space between the `-rf` and `/*`.

Comment: @xiota I disagree, warning people not to use a command is impossible without showing the actual command.

Comment: Helen, every command on a ubuntu system has thorough documentation: see `man sudo` and `man rm`

Comment: @Arronical The command didn't come out of nowhere. It's hard to believe OP did not know it is potentially dangerous. If OP is a newbie, it would have come from a list of commands known to be dangerous. If OP is not a newbie, then this could be an intentional attempt to get other people to run the command.

Comment: @xiota if OP is a newbie then some other person may be maliciously advising them to run this command, therefore letting them know it's dangerous would be a useful thing to do. There's a question on SE where somebody nuked their system because they took advice from somebody over IRC to `rm -rf` a lot of their binary storage locations, they wouldn't have done it if they'd known what the command did.

Comment: @xiota yes there's zero context, so speculatively ascribing motivation to the OP is a bit pointless. There's a nice bold warning at the top of the post and it's been closed as a duplicate now, which seems the correct way for it to be handled.

Comment: @xiota I edited again so directly copying from the title, or unthinkingly typing a stream of text from it, doesn't produce the situation you're describing. This lowers but doesn't eliminate the risk, which I think was low already. There are other older questions with comparable titles, whose OPs ran a "corrected" (i.e., much more dangerous) version of this or similar commands, sometimes to completion and sometimes not, and wanted help recovering data or reinstalling their systems. I would not retitle those. But this post is short and doesn't really benefit from a verbatim command in the title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As presented, **the command will give an error because of a typo**.

```
sudo rm -rf/*
[sudo] password for ___: 
rm: invalid option -- '/'
Try 'rm --help' for more information.
```

**Without the typo, the command would *attempt* to delete all files on the system.** It would throw errors for some files, which are inherently undeletable, such as some contained in `/proc`, `/sys`, `/dev`, or read-only file systems.

Although someone else has already indicated in comments how to correct it, I will not do so in this answer because it might cause some newbies to destroy their systems.

For more information about the `rm` command, see [`man rm`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rm.1.html).

Answer (score 9):

- `rm` = remove files
- `-r` = recursive
- `-f` = force  (ie. don't ask for confirmation)
- *The options were grouped as `-rf` to save typing.*
- `/*` = files to start removing; ie. start in / or root directory
- `sudo` elevates privileges - so the user will have write permission to everything.

In summary, that command will delete every single file on your system without any sort of confirmation.

You can run [`man rm`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/rm.1.html) to read the manual page for `rm`.

Comment: As already stated; it's a command you should **NOT** try unless it's a VM or machine you are destroying..

Comment: **This answer is incorrect.** The command in the question has a typo that would prevent it from running as this answer indicates.

Comment: I chose to ignore the typo.  I hoped it (typo) was made on purpose so idiots don't try it out, and chose not to correct that issue as it didn't impact what I was saying.